# particle visualization in Linux

Tags: linux, visualization

I have generated files of the scheme

> x \t y \t z \t charge \t type \t id

and I want to display them the in a similar way to this picture:
[image: MD result of NaCl melting]

I also need to have the ability to browse though the space of my simulation (rotate it and zoom in and out). I tried rasmol and pymol but they don't speak with my simple file format.

Is there any other tool to do this that I hadn't find?
*Edit: solution*
I have created a small program to chnge my data to the xyz format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easier to change your program to output data in one of the common formats, such as

XYZ: http://openbabel.org/wiki/XYZ_%28format%29

GRO: http://manual.gromacs.org/current/online/gro.html

Alternatively, create a tiny program to convert your data into one of the common formats. That's a lot less work than creating a visualization program from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

You could make such a plot using the [mayavi2 point3d](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html) function. Or any other [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/) based software.
Mayavi2 allows you to navigate through your 3D space and allow for stereo rendering ([press](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/application.html#keyboard-interaction) "3").

```
import enthought.mayavi.mlab as mlab
from numpy.random import random
mlab.point3d(random(1000), random(1000), random(1000),range(1000))
```

[image: point3d]

Answer (score 1):

Pymol can perfectly handle that kind of data. In your case you could just convert each point to a sphere doing soemthing like

```
pseudoatom BEAD3, pos=[26.8600, 79.4690, 135.9360], b=-67.927313
cmd.show("spheres","BEAD3")
```

for me it works nicely.